# Android map pinch zoom out issue

Tags: android, android-mapview, pinchzoom

I am using mapview in android with default pinch zoom features. But when i zoom out to a minimum level map view disappears and only tile appears in the device.. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the device has no connection to the network and is failing to download the map tiles.

Comment: Then I'd also check your Maps license key as a missing or incorrect license key can also cause the map tiles to not download